# PHP increasing boldness & font size printing to network thermal printer epson tm-t81

Tags: php, thermal-printer

I am  printing receipt using php technology on Network thermal printer (Epson Tm-t81),but the visibility of the letters on printed receipt is very low. Can u all help me to increase the boldness of the letters on Printed Reciept. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You're using PHP to talk to a printer? Is there no browser involved? Please clarify.

Comment: Hmm, this is very vague. Can you edit in the code you're using, and perhaps a photograph of the output? Can you get the printer to output a demo page, so you know that it is possible to get darker type?

Answer (score 0):

wrap the text with these:

```
$bold_on  = "\x1B\x45\x01";
$bold_off = "\x1B\x45\x00";
```